# are inline classes and UInts in kotlin safe to use?

Tags: android, kotlin

When I try to use `UInt` I get this warning message:

> This declaration is experimental and its usage should be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes' or '@OptIn(kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes::class)'

Aso the same happens when I try to create inline classes (which is what `UInt` is):

> The feature "inline classes" is experimental

Those features can be really helpful but these warning messages are just stopping me from using them in case something will break the code in the future. Is this fear realistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Experimental features** are released by Kotlin for the community to try out and provide feedback. They are by definition not completely **Stable** features, and hence

- may not have backward compatibility
- be at an early or late stage of the evolution process
- may be completely changed or even dropped in a future release

Hence you should definitely not use experimental features in critical projects as

- they are not stable and may have issues
- in case the experimental feature gets modified or dropped in a future release, you'll have the extra work of refactoring that when you upgrade Kotlin to a newer release

That being said, in case the project where you intend to use `UInt` is not critical, go ahead and use it, but just be wary of the above.

The stability of Kotlin components is very well explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/components-stability.html).